# Calling workflow from another workflow as a job in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow, powershell-jobs

I have to call a long running workflow from another workflow asynchronously. Is there a way to do that in powershell?

```
workflow CalledWorkflow
{
    Start-Sleep -s 100;
}
workflow CallingWorkflow
{
   CalledWorkflow
   "CalledWorkFlow Invoked"
}
```

Now when i call

```
CallingWorkflow
```

I need the callingworkflow to immediately return printing "CalledWorkflow 
Invoked" so that i can start continue my work while the calledworkflow is running in backgroud.

Comment: PowerShell workflows have so many [restrictions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions.aspx), it's hard to work out, if what you're trying to do is supported in some way. You can create a **Parallel** sequence in a workflow, but running workflows asynchronously... Why?

Comment: I just want to run a workflow in background I think it is possible if the calling module is a function. Any how thanks

Answer (score 0):

What environment are you running the workflows in?
In Azure Automation, you can accomplish this by starting a new job from within CallingWorkflow:

```
workflow CallingWorkFlow
{
  Start-AzureAutomationRunbook -Name CalledWorkflow -Parameters ...
  "CalledWorkFlow Invoked"
}
```

(Or Start-AzureRMAutomationRunbook for the RM version of the command).

I imagine you can do something similar in SMA, etc.